# Qt: Connecting SIGNAL to SLOT in 2 different windows

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt4

I'm going nuts trying to find the problem here.  I have a main window, and a form type window made in Qt.  I'm using the Visual Studio 2010 addon.  For some reason, my SLOT is never called in the main window; however, the signal appears to be emitted.

Here's what I've done:

This is the form:

```
class ScalerValuesWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    Ui::ScalerValuesWindow ui;

    // Variables
    std::vector<int> scalerValues;

public slots:
    void storeScalerValues();

signals:
    void ScalerValues(std::vector<int>);

public:
    ScalerValuesWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

};

void ScalerValuesWindow::storeScalerValues()
{
    emit ScalerValues(scalerValues);
    hide();
}
```

Then here's my main window connection line in my constructor:

```
scalerValuesWindow = new ScalerValuesWindow;
connect(scalerValuesWindow, SIGNAL(ScalerValues(std::vector<int>)), this, SLOT(RetrieveScalerValues(std::vector<int>)));
```

This is in my main window's class declaration:

```
public slots:
    void RetrieveScalerValues(vector<int> scalerValues);
```

And this is the slot:

```
void RelayduinoGuiThreading::RetrieveScalerValues(vector<int> scalerVals)
{
    scalerValues = scalerVals;
}
```

I have Q_OBJECT declared in both.  I have no idea what could be causing this.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define your slot as:

```
public slots:
  void RetrieveScalerValues(std::vector<int> scalerValues);
                            ^^^
```

(Inspect the generated `moc` file to see exactly what signal/slot signatures are being generated.)

Don't use `using namespace std;` in your headers, that's bad practice anyway (pulls in that huge namespace into all the users of that header, which is impolite).

Comment: Thanks so much.  I spent like an hour on that...  I don't understand why the compile didn't kick up some sort of error saying something like, "unidentified blah blah"...  Thanks again!

Comment: Much of the signal/slot matchup is done at runtime, there's not much the compiler can check. You do get a warning on the console when you try to attach to a missing slot (you should get it in your case).

Comment: I found that in one of my other files, I used namespace std.  So since I had 'using namespace std' (which I have now gotten rid of, from what you've advised), why didn't the slot work?  Shouldn't the using namespace std have told the slot that it was an std::vector<int>.  If I declared a vector<int> (no std::) elsewhere in that class (not as a slot, but as a standard function), there'd be no problem.

Comment: No, as I said, look at the moc output. signals and slots are preprocessed by something that's not a full C++ compiler and doesn't do namespace resolution (`moc`), it only does some very simple manipulations on the _text_ of the argument list of signals and slots.

Comment: Okay.  I shall look into the moc thing.  Thanks.